# flickity asNavFor not working

Tags: jquery, flickity

this really drives me nuts - everything looks nice and works fine but the click events on the thumbnails don't do anything - anyway to debug this and figure out what's going on - hope somebody has an idea how to fix this - thanks - this is my code:

```
     var galleryEl = $( '.flickity-gallery[data-id=' + id + ']' );
     var galleryNavEl = $( '.flickity-gallery-nav[data-id=' + id + ']' );
    // Main gallery
    $( galleryEl ).flickity({
        autoPlay:       false,
        //imagesLoaded: true,
        //lazyLoad:     2,
        pageDots:       false
    });

    // Thumbnail nav
    $( galleryNavEl ).flickity({
        asNavFor:           '.flickity-gallery-6666',
        cellAlign:          'center',
        contain:            true,
        pageDots:           false,
        wrapAround:         true
    });
```

Comment: Your `asNavFor` is looking for `.flickity-gallery-6666` not the dynamic created gallery elements you're creating.